# "NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource." only on Firefox

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firefox, next.js, fetch-api

I'm doing a `POST` request from my frontend using `fetch` API. But when I tried in Firefox, it doesn't work. In Chrome works fine.

Here's what I'm trying to do.

```
const handleSubmit = async event => {
        try {
            await fetch(`https://api.example.net/api/route?slug=example`, {
                method: 'post',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    'x-api-key': /* API KEY*/
                },
                body: JSON.stringify({
                    name,
                    email
                })
            })
                .then(response => console.log(response))
                .catch(err => console.log(err));
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
  };
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, guys, here's the solution.

The problem was the time for refreshing the form, is refreshing before send it. To solve this, set to refresh the form on response, and is done!

```
const handleSubmit = async event => {
        event.preventDefault();
        try {
            await fetch(`https://api.example.net/api/route?slug=example`, {
                method: 'post',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    'x-api-key': /* API KEY*/
                },
                body: JSON.stringify({
                    name,
                    email
                })
            })
                .then(response => location.reload())
                .catch(err => console.log(err));
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
  };
```

Answer (score 7):

For me it was a matter of adding event.preventDefault()

Answer (score 1):

It was a CORS problem in my case - the browser blocked the POST request because `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` response header wasn't set by the server. Setting it to '*' on the server did the job.

Answer (score 0):

If you're posting to an express server, make sure that the request and response objects are being used in your POST route on that server.  Even if you just return res.send().  None of the other solutions worked for me.