# NS_BINDING_ABORTED only on first PUT attempt in Firefox

Tags: javascript, rest, firefox

In my JS single page web app I have a reset-button that triggers 'onclick' and will use vanilla fetch() to PUT an empty JSON array to my API. Both are hosted on the same domain/server. When using Firefox (currently 86.0), the first time I push the reset button, the call is aborted. The console says `NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource` white the Network tab says `NS_BINDING_ABORTED` in the transferred column.

When I reload my app (F5) and push the same button again, it works. And also any time from now on. As the same code is executed, the failing and the working calls would send the same headers and payload.

Chrome does not show this behavior, there the first call works too.

Even stranger, this first failing PUT call in Firefox seems to only fail once per URL. The web app provides "areas" to users with the area ID in the frontend URL, e.g.

```
https://example.org/areas/#/myAreaA
```

and

```
https://example.org/areas/#/myAreaB
```

These will PUT to the API, which also has these IDs in their URLs:

```
https://example.org/api/areas/myAreaA/state/
```

and

```
https://example.org/api/areas/myAreaB/state/
```

For each of these URLs, the first PUT call fails with `NS_BINDING_ABORTED` but works thereafter. If I copy the URL for such an area into a new Tab or even close+open the Browser again, the Error does not appear again. The web app does not use any cookies.

The web app does a lot of other API calls to the same backend/areaID, no other show this behavior. However, this is the only PUT call, all other calls are GET/POST/HEAD/PATCH requests.

What could be the reason for the first PUT failing?

Comment: Side note: this also happens in a fresh Firefox profile without any (blocker) plugins active.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following ["NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource." only on Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59176488/networkerror-when-attempting-to-fetch-resource-only-on-firefox) I found the problem. It seems that Firefox' onclick event propagation interferes here with the fetch() call. As soon as I added

```
event.preventDefault()
```

in the onclick-handler *before* doing the actual fetch(), everything started to work again.