# The script is not working in Mozilla Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, request

I need to send some data to the server when the page is closed or refreshed. Therefore, I created a simple script that can handle my needs. The problem is that this script is **not working in Mozilla firefox**.

The script is working in many other browsers like chrome, chromium, brave, opera, falkon, epiphany, qutebroser, Midori, safari, edge. **The problem is only with firefox**.

```
var timeLog = {
    start: null,
    end: null,

    init: function () {
        this.start = new Date().getTime();
    },

    sendResults: function () {
        this.end = new Date().getTime();
        var url = "tracker";
        url += "?" + "start=" + this.start;
        url += "&" + "end=" + this.end;
        url += "&" + "User-Agent-JS=" + navigator.userAgent;
        url += "&" + "url=" + window.location.toString();

        fetch(url, {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
            keepalive: true
        });
    }
};

window.onbeforeunload = function () {
    timeLog.sendResults();
};

timeLog.init();
```

**The error message is:**
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource.

EDIT:
if the event for onbeforeunload is registred as here:

```
window.onbeforeunload = async function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    timeLog.sendResults();
};
```

it is working, but I need to confirm that I want to leave the page.

[image]

As I found on the internet, the problem arises because firefox uses its own implementation of *fetch*.

-----------------------SOLUTION [still not working in firefox correctly]-------------------------

```
window.onbeforeunload = function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    timeLog.sendResults();
    delete event['returnValue'];
};
```

-----------------------SOLUTION-------------------------

I used sendBeacon instead of fetch

so the final code is following:

```
/*      ----REPLACED----
        fetch(url, {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
            keepalive: true
        });
*/        
        navigator.sendBeacon(url);
```

Comment: what about the error message ?

Comment: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource." only on Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59176488/networkerror-when-attempting-to-fetch-resource-only-on-firefox)

Comment: adding preventDefault makes weird behaviour of onbeforeunload. I hope, this can be solved in better way

Comment: It seems odd to me to "fetch" when unloading instead of  ajax POST.

Comment: with ajax it does not fire when the tab is closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's add a bit more code to see what is going on, allow the `fetch` to complete then process any error (pause to see it) then proceed to the unload if no error happened - our desired case.

```js
var timeLog = {
  start: null,
  end: null,

  init: function() {
    this.start = new Date().getTime();
  },

  sendResults: function() {
    this.end = new Date().getTime();
    var url = "tracker";
    url += "?" + "start=" + this.start;
    url += "&" + "end=" + this.end;
    url += "&" + "User-Agent-JS=" + navigator.userAgent;
    url += "&" + "url=" + window.location.toString();

    return fetch(url, {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      keepalive: true
    });
  }
};

window.addEventListener('beforeunload', function(e) {
  // Cancel the event
  // e.preventDefault(); // If you prevent default behavior in Mozilla Firefox prompt will always be shown
  // Chrome requires returnValue to be set
  // e.returnValue = '';

  let myfetch = timeLog.sendResults();
  myfetch
    // borrowed code https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch
    .then(response => {
      //do something with response
      const contentType = response.headers.get('content-type');
      if (!contentType || !contentType.includes('application/json')) {
        throw new TypeError("Oops, we haven't got JSON!");
      }
      return response.json();
    })
    .then(data => {
      /* process your data further */
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.error(error);
      e.preventDefault(); // pause to see the error in console
    });
  // the absence of a returnValue property on the event will guarantee the browser unload happens
  delete e['returnValue'];
});

timeLog.init();
```

Comment: The error is:
TypeError: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource. visitorTracker.js:52:17
    <anonymous> http://localhost:8080/webapp2/scripts/visitorTracker.js:52
    (Async: promise callback)
    <anonymous> http://localhost:8080/webapp2/scripts/visitorTracker.js:51
    (Async: EventListener.handleEvent)
    <anonymous> http://localhost:8080/webapp2/scripts/visitorTracker.js:32

Comment: But I found that it works with onunload function, and event must call prevetDefault

Comment: your answer helped me a lot. Thanks. Adding delete e['returnValue'] solved my probem.